# Cómo puedo sumar dos nodos hijos de un arbol en java?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

De que forma puedo sumar dos nodos hijos de un árbol en JAVA si mi clase nodoArbol esta definida de la siguiente forma:

```
public class NodoArbol <T>  {
 public T nodeValue;
 public NodoArbol <T> der;
 public NodoArbol <T> izq;

 NodoArbol () {
     this.nodeValue = null;
     this.der = null;
     this.izq = null;
 }

 NodoArbol(T d) {
     this.nodeValue = d;
     this.der = null;
     this.izq = null;
 }
```

}

Cual seria la forma correcta en la que debo de realziar la operacion de los nodos de la izquierda y la derecha de un arbol de busqueda binaria?

Comment: ¿Algún ejemplo dónde está el árbol que has creado?

Comment: Estoy leyendo un archivo txt con datos como: 73
45
90
15
60
82
115
11
22
58
64
75
86
300

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega todo lo que creas conveniente para que cualquier usuario de la comunidad pueda reproducir tu escenario :D

Comment: Como comentario te voy a decir que para que sea un arbol el nodo tiene que tener un padre.